# Diagnose failed deployment

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, java-ee-6, weblogic11g

I have to deploy an EAR archive corresponding to a Java EE application in a client's WebLogic server. I have full access to Enterprise Manager but I'm not allowed to deploy through it—instead, I need to invoke a web service that triggers a home-brew shell script. I can see its source code: it first attempts to undeploy the app and (no matter the result) then attempts to deploy the uploaded EAR; each task call a Python script and that's where I lose track. I believe actual work is eventually done by Java libraries from [WebLogic Scripting Tool](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28271_01/web.1111/e13715/using_wlst.htm).

The problem is that I'm not getting any error code or message but the application stubbornly remains in its previous release. I'm positively sure there's nothing wrong with the EAR. I've recompiled everything several times and it deploys successfully to the staging server (where I do use EM).

Is there any log file to be found either in Enterprise Manager or Administration Console?

Comment: You should first read WebLogic Server's logs, if there is any issue with your application deployment logs will have exceptions and stack traces.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin Thank you for the tip, but that's basically what I'm asking: "Is there any log file to be found either in Enterprise Manager or Administration Console". Admin tools are vast and their layout is not obvious for someone who isn't familiar with the technology. (Meanwhile, client's IT staff finally told me that deployment wasn't even running due to a bug in their in-house cron wrapper—honestly, I don't have a clue about how reliable this information is).

Comment: the best way is to read log directly from the file system. If you cannot access to the machine you can have a look to log files using the admin Console. In the left pane of the Console, expand Diagnostics and select Log Files. In the Log Files table, select the radio button next to the server log file and Click View.